# Slightly mispositioned hyperlink to start of tabularx environment

Tags: hyperref, tabularx

I'm writing a document where I have to put a lot of similar tables (and I have to keep them "similar"). 
So I'm writing some macros to generate and partially fill the tables automatically. (I generate the table passing to the macro an item key, so that I can get automatically the ID, the Title, and some other information.)
This for explaining that I need to use the macros..

This works (suprisingly) well except for a slighty mis-positioned link to the tables, it "cuts" the title line.
That is, if you click on "link" it goes (slightly) too far down on the page, and the table isn't fully visible and you have to scroll up. I think That depends on the viewer used ( some link to the page, some other to the extact line). I'm using the one integrated in TexStudio.

Here a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}       
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}   

\newcommand\mytitle[1]{\phantomsection A title generated from a key\label{test}}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l  X } 
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mytitle}  \\
                \midrule
                ID & \dots \\ 
                \addlinespace[1em] 
                etc. &  \dots \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
        }

\begin{document} 
    Link to title table: \hyperref[test]{link}

    \pagebreak

    \mytab

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `cuts the title` mean? I see the full title!

Comment: Yeah, me too.
But if you click on "link" it goes (slightly) too down on the page, and the table isn't fully visible and you have to scroll up.


I think That depends on the viewer used ( some link to the page, some other to the extact line).
I'm using the one integrated in TexStudio

Comment: Yes, this viewer dependent and has nothing to the with `LaTeX` actually, in my point of view. On Adobe Reader (Linux) the full table is shown

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I think the OP *meant* to say that if the pdf file is displayed in full width on the screen and one then clicks on the link on page 1, the pdf browswer (Acrobat, say) performs a jump to page 2 (the one with the table) in such a way that the title line of the table is only partially visible.

Comment: Nice to know, thank you very much! :)
edit. Mico, yes extactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ChristianHupfer has already pointed out in a comment, the issue you're experiencing is mainly related to the pdf browswer you're employing.

If switching pdf browswers is not a viable option, you could try the following remedy: Move the `\phantomsection` and `\label` statements to the very start of the `\mytab` macro.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\mylink[1]{\phantomsection\label{#1}}
\newcommand\mytitle[1]{\textbf{#1}}  % set appearance of title string

% \mytab now takes two arguments: the label string and the title string
\newcommand\mytab[2]{\mylink{#1}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l  X }
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\mytitle{#2}}  \\
                \midrule
                ID & \dots \\
                \addlinespace[1em]
                etc. &  \dots \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
        }

\begin{document}
    Link to table's title line: \hyperref[lab:test]{link}

    \pagebreak

    \mytab{lab:test}{A title generated from a key}

\end{document}
```